# Mailitem SentOn time in Sent Items folder is not the same in Inbox

Tags: outlook-addin

My test case scenario is a user sends email to herself, i.e. To and From accounts are the same.
When email is sent, I record the SentOn time of the sent email. I use the Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler event handler attached to the Sent Item folder to pick up this time. 
Few seconds later, email arrives to Inbox. However, when I get SentOn time of the Inbox email, it is different to the SentOn time of the sent email. The difference is consistent and it is about one second in all my tests. I wonder if it is a normal Outlook 2016 behaviour or I am missing something? Should these SentOn dates be the same for both emails?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is to be expected - for the outgoing messages, PR_CLIENT_SUBMIT_TIME is set based on the current date stamp. On the incoming messages, PR_CLIENT_SUBMIT_TIME is extracted from Date MIME header. The two are not necessarily the same, especially if Exchange server sends the messages.

Comment: Dmitry, thank you for your response. I did not mention in my post that if From and To accounts were different, the SentOn time of the  sent and incoming emails were the same in all my tests. How could it be? Thanks

Comment: Is this an Exchange mailbox? Are you sending through Exchange or SMTP?

Comment: Yes. It is Exchange 2013 mailbox and email is sent through Exchange. Strangely, when I debug the code the SentOn dates of incoming and outcoming eamils are often the same. May it be because I am debugging slowly and email gets sent and received in the background?

Comment: It depends on how much off your local and Exchnage server clocks are. Did you look at milliseconds  in OutlookSpy?

Comment: Hi Dmitry, just to let you know, we have investigated the time difference and it turned out that the email delivery delay was caused by bouncing email between two our Exchange servers: Ecxhange 2007 and Exchange 2013. They both in work in our development environment because we are in transition stage at the moment.

Comment: Also, the client pc was synced with incorrect domain controller and our Exchange 2013 had a problem similar to thishttps://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/66f0629f-21fb-444b-b3f1-99ed8a4f52b2/slow-mail-flow?forum=exchangesvrsecuremessaging.  Meanwhile, I have downloaded the OutlookSpy and tried to look into milliseconds that you mentioned. Is it in IMessage window?

Comment: Yes, click IMessage, select the PR_CLIENT_SUBMIT_TIME property, click the "..." button next to the Value edit box.

Comment: What I've found out is the PR_CLIENT_SUBMIT_TIME of outgoing and incoming messages is not the same in the most of my tests. The ValidFlagStringProof time of outgoing and incoming messages is the same in all cases. It can be used to identify an email instead of using PR_CLIENT_SUBMIT_TIME in the code. However, it is not clear how to retrieve it in the managed code. I wonder if it is possible to get ValidFlagStringProof time using Redemption software? Thanks

Comment: You can retrieve that property in Redemption using Fields[] or PropertyAccessor.GetProperty - pass the DASL property name (you can see it in OutlookSpy IMessage window).

Comment: PropertyAccessor works for me. Thanks a lot for your help. I like OutlookSpy. We'll buy it.